# How find a Item of QListWidget with findItem?

Tags: python, pyqt4, graphic

How find a Item of QListWidget with findItem, set a String "Example".
How do it bottom ?

```
   if QlistWidget HAVE a "String Example":
           return True
   else:
           return False
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in the documentation:

```
out = lw.findItems("String Example", QtCore.Qt.MatchExactly)
return len(out) > 0
```

where lw is your QListWidget. `out` is a list of matching items.

Comment: Go unnoticed because they do not understand English very well . Thank You very much!